# Why vishnu on ksheera sagara?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi, adisesha

Lord Vishnu rests on Ananta-Shesha, together with his consort Goddess Lakshmi, who is massaging His feet in Ksheera Sagar. I want to ask what message is being passed through this to a common man. I feel there is something which i don't know on this great "Ananta Shayana". Can any one help me on this.

Comment: Do you think goddess Lakshmi always massages Vishnu feet? She is in His Heart. He is called as **SRINIVASA**. SRI(opulence aka Lakshmi) resides (NIVASA) in him.He was Vyuha Vasudeva aka Narayana, who lives on Kseera Sagara, a manifestation of supreme Brahman, who protects the cosmos. Allegorical meaning could be related to Yoga.